# Reading in a .txt file in Java

Tags: java, file

I am trying to write a program which reads in a a list of nodes that interact with each other within a network. This is written in a text file in the format:

```
node1   node2
node1   node3
node2   node3
node3   node5
```

This indicates node1 interacts with node2 and node3, node 2 interacts with only node3 etc.

The program will be able to read in this file and will remove any repeated interactions and will be able to return to me the number of interactions a node has with other nodes if I input the name of the node. However, I am very new to Java and am first trying to get it to read in the file, although my code does not read in the file at the moment. Here is the code I have so far:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadFile {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      File myObj = new File("interactions.txt");
      Scanner FileReader = new Scanner(myObj);
      while (FileReader.hasNextLine()) {
        String data = FileReader.nextLine();
        System.out.println(data);
      }
      FileReader.close();
    } 
  }
}
```

Any help on how to solve this would be really appreciated, thank you!

Comment: hey, welcome to SO. result do you get? Also, you should add a `catch` block after the `try` so that you can see any errors that are thrown.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a full running answer if you are still interested...

For input file:

```
 node1   node2
 node1   node3
 node2   node3
 node3   node5
 node2   node3 <<< repeating
 node2   node6
 node1   node3 <<< repeating
```

The filtered output:

```
 node1   node2 
 node1   node3 
 node2   node3 
 node3   node5 
 node2   node6
```

**SHORT ANSWER:**
Use HashMap<String, String> and

check repeating nodes with
x_nodes.containsKey(x_key) && x_nodes.containsValue(x_value)

**DETAILED ANSWER:**
Copy & paste the following source:

```
public static char       q_TEXT_SEPARATOR            = '|';
public static int        q_MAX_TEXT_LINE_NBR         = 1000;
public static char       q_ALT_ENTER                 = '\n';
public static String     q_CUSTOM_COMMENT_CHAR       = "*";
public static String     q_CUSTOM_SPLIT_CHAR         = " ";

public static HashMap<String, String> w_nodes = new HashMap<String, String>();



public static boolean empty_line(String input) {
    boolean w_bos_bilgi = (input == null || input.equals("") || input.trim().equals(""));
    return  w_bos_bilgi;
}

public static String[] custom_split(String s) {
    return custom_split(s, q_TEXT_SEPARATOR);
}
public static String[] custom_split(String s, char   q_TEXT_SEPARATOR) {
    String[] p = new String[q_MAX_TEXT_LINE_NBR];
    for (int i = 0; i < q_MAX_TEXT_LINE_NBR; i++) {
        p[i] = "";
    }

    int totlen = s.length();
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;
    boolean finish = false;
    while (!finish) {
        if ((k >= totlen) || (i >= q_MAX_TEXT_LINE_NBR)) {
            finish = true;
        } else {
            String w_tx = "";
            boolean finish2 = false;
            while (!finish2) {
                char c = s.charAt(k);
                if ((  c      ==      q_TEXT_SEPARATOR)  || (k > totlen) || (i == q_MAX_TEXT_LINE_NBR)) {
                    finish2 = true;
                } else {
                    if (c != q_ALT_ENTER) {
                        w_tx = w_tx + c;
                    }
                    k = k + 1;
                }
            }
            if (!empty_line(w_tx)) {
                p[i] = w_tx;
                i++;
            }
            k++;
        }
    }

    return p;
}

public static boolean existing(HashMap<String, String> x_nodes, String x_key, String x_value) {
    if ( x_nodes.containsKey(x_key) && x_nodes.containsValue(x_value) ) {return false;}
    else                                                                {return true;}
}

public static void import_nodes() {
   String q_NODES_FILENAME = "C://...//interactions.txt";

   BufferedReader q_NODES_in = null;
   try {
        q_NODES_in           = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(q_NODES_FILENAME));
   } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("> WARNING : Nodes file not found !");
        return;
   }


   String w_file_str = "", w_line = "";
   while ( q_NODES_in != null && w_line != null ) {
       try {
         w_line        = q_NODES_in.readLine();
         if ( empty_line(w_line) ) {continue;}
         if ( w_line.startsWith(q_CUSTOM_COMMENT_CHAR)) {continue;}

         if  ( w_line == null || w_line.equals("null") ) {
              throw new IOException();
         }

         w_file_str   += w_line.replace(q_TEXT_SEPARATOR + "", "") + q_TEXT_SEPARATOR;
       } catch (Exception e) {
           break;
       }
   }
   try {q_NODES_in.close();} catch (Exception e) {}

   if ( empty_line(w_file_str) ) {
          System.out.println("> WARNING : Nodes file empty !");
          return;
   }


   String p[] = custom_split(w_file_str);
   for (int i = 0; i < p.length && !empty_line(p[i]); i++) {
       String w_key   = "";
       String w_node = (p[i] + " ");
       int    w_separator = w_node.indexOf(q_CUSTOM_SPLIT_CHAR);
       if   ( w_separator < 0 ) {continue;}
       else                 {w_key   = w_node.substring(0, w_separator);
                             w_node = w_node.substring(w_separator + 1);}

       if ( p[i].trim().toUpperCase().startsWith(q_CUSTOM_COMMENT_CHAR)) {continue;}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     //UPD 2012/10/08

       if ( existing(w_nodes, w_key, w_node)      ) {
            w_nodes.put(w_key, w_node);
            System.out.println(w_key + " " + w_node);
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because file doesn't exists in the location that you are looking.
You probably missed the catch clause, where you can print the exact exception.

First, try to run this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try {
        File myObj = new File("interactions.txt");
        Scanner FileReader = new Scanner(myObj);
        while (FileReader.hasNextLine()) {
            String data = FileReader.nextLine();
            System.out.println(data);
        }
        FileReader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

File should be at the root level of project, this might help you as well

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try {
        File myObj = new File("interactions.txt");

        // check if file exists - if not - create
        if (myObj.createNewFile()) {
            System.out.println("File created: " + myObj.getName());
        } else {
            System.out.println("File already exists.");
        }
        Scanner FileReader = new Scanner(myObj);
        while (FileReader.hasNextLine()) {
            String data = FileReader.nextLine();
            System.out.println(data);
        }
        FileReader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just a little example how you can encapsulate your code for the task. Excuse my grammar please, i hope you can read it.

```java
// extends means that the class will inherit properties of HashMap
// Parameters between <> are generics, they determinate the types
// that are used as keys and values and same goes for HashSet, It does not matter
// what you substitute here as long as its not a buildin type (so not int but 
// Integer), if you dont know what hashmap is or dont understand generics, search 
// it on internet
public class Network extends HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> {
        // this is a constructor as it is named the same as Class and hes not 
        // return type specified. in this case we are initializin contents of the 
        // map and throws specifies that this Method can fail and what it can   
        // throw, this is java vay of passing errors up and leaving caller to 
        // handle then.
        public Network(String filename) throws IOException {
                // This is what i hate about java and that are buffer readers
                // this isnt that bad but if you get like 4 nested to each other...
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
                
                while(true) {
                    String line = reader.readLine();
                    if(line == null) return; // null signalizes we read all lines
                    // look for dosc of String.split if you dont know what it 
                    // does
                    String[] nds = line.split(" ");
                    // as you can see we can call methods of Hashmap, like 
                    // computeIfAbsent, as if it was member of Network. That 
                    // wierd arrow is an lambda expression, search for java lambda 
                    // expressions to learn more, same goes for computeIfAbsent
                    HashSet<String> set = computeIfAbsent(nds[0], k -> new HashSet<>());
                    // Finally as ewerithing in java is pointer except some 
                    // simple types we can modify set like so. Good thing about 
                    // set is that i takes care of ensuring that we have no 
                    // duplicates 
                    set.add(nds[1]);
                }
        }

        // a simple abstraction that encapsulates logic, as i dont like returning 
        // null in this case, throwing an exception makes it more obvious, though
        // of corse you might change it for better user experiance as writing try
        // catchs ewriwhare is annoying
        public int getInteractionCountFor(String nodeName) throws NoSuchElementException {
            HashSet<String> set = get(nodeName);
            if (set == null) {
                // throwing our own exception with custom message
                throw new NoSuchElementException("the network does not contain " + nodeName);
            }
            return  set.size();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @DavidSmith i added lot of comments but you also have to search things